# Control is not going inside @KafkaListner method and no message is printing in java console

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I have created messaging component which will be called by other service for consuming and sending message from kafka, producer part is working fine, I am not sure what wrong with the below consumer listner part why it not printing messages or in debug mode control also not going inside the @kafkaListner method, but GUI based kafkamanager app shows offset is got committed even thought its mannual offset commit.

**Here is my Message listner class code , I have checked topic and groupid is setting and fetched properly**

> ```
> @Component
> public class SpringKafkaMessageListner {
>
> public CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
>
>   @KafkaListener(topics = "#{consumerFactory.getConfigurationProperties().get(\"topic-name\")}",
>           groupId = "#{consumerFactory.getConfigurationProperties().get(\"group.id\")}",
>           containerFactory = "springKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
>   public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack) {
>       System.out.println("listening...");
>       System.out.println("Received Message in group : "
>               + " and message: " + consumerRecord.value());
>       System.out.println("current offsetId : " + consumerRecord.offset());
>       ack.acknowledge();
>       latch.countDown();
>   }
> ```
>
> }

**Consumer config class-**

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableKafka
> public class KafkaConsumerBeanConfig<T> {
>
>   @Autowired
>   @Lazy
>   private KafkaConsumerConfigDTO kafkaConsumerConfigDTO;
>
> @Bean
>   public ConsumerFactory<Object, T> consumerFactory() {
>     return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaConsumerConfigDTO.getConfigs());
>   }
>
>  //for spring kafka with manual offset commit
>   @Bean
>   public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object,
>   springKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
>     ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, T> factory =
>             new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
>     factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
>     //manual commit
>     
>   factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
>     return factory;
>   }
>
>
>  @Bean
>   SpringKafkaMessageListner consumerListner(){
>     return new SpringKafkaMessageListner();
>   }
> }
> ```

**Below code snippet is consumer interface implementation which expose subscribe() method and all other bean creation is done thru ConfigurableApplicationContext.**

> ```
>  public class SpringKafkaConsumer<T> implements Consumer<T> {
>
>  public SpringKafkaConsumer(ConsumerConfig<T> consumerConfig,
>                        ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
>     this.consumerConfig = consumerConfig;
>     this.context = context;
>     this.consumerFactory =  context.getBean("consumerFactory", ConsumerFactory.class);
>     this.springKafkaContainer =  context.getBean("springKafkaListenerContainerFactory",
>     ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.class);
>   
>   }
>
>    // here is it just simple code to initialize SpringKafkaMessageListner class and invoking  
>     listening part
>  @Override
>     public void subscribe() {
>     consumerListner = context.getBean("consumerListner", SpringKafkaMessageListner.class);
>       try {
>         consumerListner.latch.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
>
>       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>    }
>   }
> }
> ```

**Test class with my local docker kafka setup**

> ```
> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
> @DirtiesContext
> @ContextConfiguration(classes = QueueManagerSpringConfig.class)
> public class SpringKafkaTest  extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
>
>
>
>  @Autowired
> private QueueManager queueManager;
> private Consumer<KafkaMessage> consumer;`
>
>
>   // test method   
>  @Test
>   public void testSubscribeWithLocalBroker() {
>     String topicName = "topic1";
>     String brokerServer = "127.0.0.1:9092";
>     String groupId = "grp1";
>     Map<String, String> additionalProp = new HashMap<>();
>     additionalProp.put(KafkaConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID, groupId);
>     additionalProp.put(KafkaConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT, "false");
>     additionalProp.put(KafkaConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL, "100");
>     ConsumerConfig<KafkaMessage> consumerConfig =
>             new ConsumerConfig.Builder<>(topicName, new KafkaSuccessMessageHandler(new 
>             KafkaMessageSerializerTest()),
>                     new KafkaMessageDeserializerTest())
>                     .additionalProperties(additionalProp)
>                     .enableSpringKafka(true)
>                     .offsetPositionStrategy(new EarliestPositionStrategy())
>                     .build();
>     consumer = queueManager.getConsumer(consumerConfig);
>     System.out.println("start subscriber");
>     // calling subcribe method of consumer that will invoke kafkalistner
>     consumer.subscribe();
> }
>
>
>  @Configuration 
>  public class QueueManagerSpringConfig {  
>  @Bean  
>  public QueueManager queueManager() {
>  Map<String, String> kafkaProperties = new HashMap<>();
>  kafkaProperties.put(KafkaPropertyNamespace.NS_PREFIX +     
>  KafkaPropertyNamespace.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
>         "127.0.0.1:9092");
>
> return QueueManagerFactory.getInstance(new KafkaPropertyNamespace(kafkaProperties));   } }
> ```

Comment: You seem to have a lot of unnecessary complications so it's hard to see exactly what you are doing. However, you need to set the consumer property `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`. By default it is `latest` in which case the consumer is positioned at the end of the topic.

Comment: @GaryRussell , Thanks for quick reply , the issue was on the custom deserializer side, with normal StringDeserilzer was able to see the message printing in console